# How to use class PCA from matplotlib for face recognition?

Tags: python, matplotlib, face-recognition, pca

I am trying to build a code for face recognition using python. Now I am able to put all my database images into one two-dimensional array to be able to apply Principal component analysis (PCA) on them. I found a class called PCA in matplotlib but I am wondering how to use it for face recognition.

Here is the description of the mentioned class:

```
class matplotlib.mlab.PCA(a)
compute the SVD of a and store data for PCA. Use project to project the data onto a reduced set of dimensions

Inputs:

a: a numobservations x numdims array
Attrs:

a a centered unit sigma version of input a

numrows, numcols: the dimensions of a

mu : a numdims array of means of a

sigma : a numdims array of atandard deviation of a

fracs : the proportion of variance of each of the principal components

Wt : the weight vector for projecting a numdims point or array into PCA space

Y : a projected into PCA space

The factor loadings are in the Wt factor, ie the factor loadings for the 1st principal component are given by Wt[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

They key concept is you project faces into a higher dimensional space and then measure distances between them in that space.

I'm quoting from this document (looks like an assignment for a class):

http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~knkim/KG_VISA/PCA/FaceRecog_PCA_Kim.pdf

"PCA computes the basis of a space which is represented by its training vectors. These basis vectors, actually eigenvectors, computed by PCA are in the direction of the largest variance of the training vectors. As it has been said earlier, we call them eigenfaces.

Each eigenface can be viewed a feature. When a particular face is projected onto the face space, its vector into the face space describe the importance of each of those features in the face. The face is expressed in the face space by its eigenface coeﬃcients (or weights). We can handle a large input vector, facial image, only by taking its small weight vector in the face space. This means that we can reconstruct the original face with some error, since the dimensionality of the image space is much larger than that of face space.

In this report, let’s consider face identiﬁcation only. Each face in the training set is transformed into the face space and its components are stored in memory. The face space has to be populated with these known faces. An input face is given to the system, and then it is projected onto the face space. The system computes its distance from all the stored faces."

There are several tutorials available.  Here are my favorites:

- http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html

  http://www.tp.umu.se/~nylen/pylect/advanced/scikit-learn/index.html#id9

  http://www.janeriksolem.net/2009/01/pca-for-images-using-python.html

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.